# Trimming all strings from an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, trim

I used this code to  get the contents of a directory:

```
string[] savefile = Directory.GetFiles(mcsdir, "*.bin");
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(savefile);
```

and it returns as

```
C:\Users\Henry\MCS\save1.bin
C:\Users\Henry\MCS\save2.bin
```

How can I make it return as only

```
save1.bin
save2.bin
```

Please note that this app will be used by other people, so the name is not always "Henry".
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
var strs = savefile.Select(a => Path.GetFileName(a)).ToArray();
```

**Looking at the suggestion of minitech**:
As long as you get the array of type `FileInfo[]` there is no need to convert it to string array. Just set the property `DisplayMember` to the property name you want to display in your `ComboBox`.

```
FileInfo[] savefile = new DirectoryInfo(mcsdir).GetFiles("*.bin");
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.DataSource = savefile;
```

Using this you keep your original `FileInfo[]` array with all additional information (as to the full path to your files) and same time display only the short filenames (without path) in your control.

*(I assume that your question is about WinForms. If you are using Silverlight or WPF you need to set the property using the "Target" attribute).*

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` instead, and LINQ:

```
FileInfo[] savefile = new DirectoryInfo(mcsdir).GetFiles("*.bin");
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(savefile.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll use this one... Since your other answer returns strings.

Comment: @user1067461: It's not my answer :) I just edited it because it didn't have a period at the end. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Path.GetFileName(string path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).